# How to test that a python class does not subclass a protocol

Tags: python, python-typing

I need to make sure that developers on my team are not directly subclassing a `typing.Protocol` instance. That is, although their classes should implement the interface of the Protocol, we don't want:

```
class MyClass(MyProtocol):
    # inherits MyProtocol
```

which would coerce the class to be a subclass of the Protocol and, therefore, necessarily pass `isinstance(MyClass(), MyProtocol)` even if it does not implement any logic in the attributes and methods of the class.

Example of the problem:

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Don't subclass MyProtocol!")

class MyClass(MyProtocol):
    pass

# MyClass now has foo since it inherits the Protocol...
assert hasattr(MyClass(), 'foo')
```

In other words, I would like a test of the form:

```
def does_not_subclass_protocol(obj, protocol):
    # returns True if and only if obj does not have
    # MyClass(MyProtocol)...
    # syntax in class definition.
```

Comment: Just check for `MyProtocol` in the class's method resolution order?

Comment: It sounds like `MyProtocol` should be an abstract base class. This forces the subclasses to implement the methods themselves.

Comment: Couldn't you just `return Protocol not in type(obj).__mro__`? Or are you only checking this for specific subclasses of `Protocol`?

Comment: The `__mro__` suggestion does the trick. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prohibit subclassing in the Protocol and use `typing.runtime_checkable`:

```
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable


@runtime_checkable
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def foo(self): ...
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError
```

<sub>I don't know whether the type checker will ignore the magic method `__init_subclass__` because I can only test on my mobile phone now.</sub>

Direct implementation Protocol:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def foo(self):
...         print('hello')
...
>>> isinstance(MyClass(), MyProtocol)
True
```

Inheritance agreement:

```
>>> class MyClass(MyProtocol): pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/abc.py", line 106, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __init_subclass__
TypeError
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. In this case, I'm actually writing on-boarding materials and the developers need to write code which is then checked against a series of tests, so I need a test of the form above. The protocols in our code base don't implement this and we're probably not going to add for the sake of on-boarding. Though I may pass this idea along. Accepting, since it answers the question of the title.